# Oracle Forms 6i Err: 201 Identifire or No Column In Table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, identity-column, undeclared-identifier

Can anybody help ?

I Have a table Named "`Cut_Issue`" One of its column is "`TRANS_NO`".

The Code is:

```
Select Trans_No 
into :Cut_issue.Trans_NO 
from Mlang.cut_issue 
where Trans_No = :sc.Trans_NO;
```

- `:Cut_issue` (Data Block)
- `:SC` (DATA BLOCK)
- `Mlang` (Database USER)

Sometimes I found Error :

> No Column Trans_No in Table

and Some Times

> Identifier Trans_NO Must be Declare

What can be issue. My mind has stuck.

Comment: Seems like the conflict of the table usage? Why are you accessing the table cut_issue with schema name prefix? What is the data source of the cut_issue in the form ?

Comment: I tried , Both Ways , With and without Schema name. The data source is the same  Cut_Issue on the form .

Comment: Then I would ask if the table is same why you try to fetch it again from table and put into the same block.item. why not just do execute query by passing the sc.trans_no?

Comment: Cut_issue is not linked Table with SC Table ... 
I get Trans_NO from SC and add ref Trans_No in Cut_issue then  Add quantity etc. etc.

Comment: No what I mean is "Select Trans_No into :Cut_issue.Trans_NO from Mlang.cut_issue where Trans_No = :sc.Trans_NO;" ..what is this for ? And in which trigger you have written this ?

Comment: I am Trying if the Trans_No is present in Cut_issue then Show Me its Quantity Else Put The Trans No in it so that I add its quantity and save the Record .

Comment: Could you post the `cut_issue` table's description? Please, use SQL*Plus to do that - copy/paste result of `desc cut_issue` (edit the question; don't put it into a comment).

Comment: @Tera - when you say you get the error sometimes, is this when you are running forms whilst connected as a different user?

Answer (score 0):

I think `Cut_issue` block has `Query Data Source Name` filled with the name of a table which has no such column called `Trans_No`. Most probably, a field named `Trans_No` dragged from the tool palette. That should have `Database Item` attribute within the `Database` node of the Property Palette is set to **`Yes`** as *default*. Besides, that item might have `column name` within the `Database` node set to `Trans_No`.

If you meet such a case, then just set the value of `Database Item` attribute to **`No`** (*no matter what's written for the column name in this case*)